# Why is this code snippet not working?

Tags: debugging, scripting, vbscript

```
Class GetDate
    Private internal_strDate
    Private internal_strDay
    Private internal_strMonth
    Private internal_strYear
    Private internal_Debug

    Public Property Set isdebug(ByRef vLine)
        internal_Debug = vLine
        WScript.Echo("in debug mode: " & internal_Debug) 
    End Property

    Public Property Get GetFormattedDate
        internal_strDate = CDate(Date)
        internal_strYear = DatePart("yyyy", internal_strDate)
        internal_strMonth = DatePart("m", internal_strDate)
        internal_strDay = DatePart("d", internal_strDate)

        If internal_strMonth < 10 Then
            internal_strMonth = "0" & internal_strMonth
        End If
        If internal_strDay < 10 Then
            internal_strDay = "0" & internal_strDay
        End If
        GetFormattedDate = internal_strYear & "-" & internal_strMonth & "-" & internal_strDay
    End Property
End Class
```

After my class definition, I have this code and it gives me an error.

```
Dim objYear
Set objYear = New GetDate
objYear.isdebug(True)
```

The error says

> in debug mode: False Microsoft VBScript runtime error (68, 1) : Object
>   doesn't support this property or method: 'isdebug'

Basically, I want to be able to set the debug to true and then I'm going to modify the GetFormattedDate property to check if 'internal_Debug' is on and if it is then let me enter the date manually. (instead of obtaining the date automagically)

Comment: Minor point, but your `GetFormattedDate` function can be reduced down to `GetFormattedDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")` and will be more reliable in different locales (as it's not going through string conversion beforehand)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure that you instanced the class properly, like so:

```
Dim objYear 
Set objYear = New GetDate
objYear.isdebug(True)
```

**Update #1**

I misread your code, isdebug is a property, modify your Class a little so the "isdebug" becomes:

```
Public Property Let isdebug(ByRef vLine)
    internal_Debug = vLine
    WScript.Echo("in debug mode: " & internal_Debug) 
End Property
```

Then you use it like this:

```
objYear.isdebug = True
```

Or, change it to this:

```
Public Sub isdebug(ByRef vLine)
    internal_Debug = vLine
    WScript.Echo("in debug mode: " & internal_Debug) 
End Sub
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
objYear.isdebug(True)
```

Comment: Genius! A little word like Set to Let made a huge difference. Where can I read about the various verbs and when to use them?

Comment: Try this one, I think it explains Get/Set/Let pretty well: http://qtp.blogspot.com/2007/08/vbscript-property-let-property-get.html

Answer (score 1):

`isdebug` is a property, so your code should be:

```
Dim objYear
Set objYear = New GetDate
objYear.isdebug = True
```

**Edit:**

Change

```
Public Property Set isdebug(ByRef vLine)
```

to

```
Public Property Let isdebug(ByRef vLine)
```

`Property Set` is for objects while `Property Let` is for value types.

Comment: Same error message comes with this. I've tried this before However I retested incase I madea  typo. Error message reads "Microsoft VBScript runtime error (68, 1) : Object doesn't support this property or method: 'isdebug'"

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were using Set instead of Let for your isdebug property. I've changed my answer so the wrong one doesn't live on in perpetuity.